# Webpack with typescript getting TypeScript emitted no output error

Tags: typescript, webpack

I've got this configuration from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader:

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    entry: "./src/Api.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

./src/Api.ts:

```
export class Api {
...
}
```

But when I run webpack I get:

```
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for Api.ts
```

Comment: (Just a shot in the dark) Do you by chance have any outdated compiled javascript in the same directory as your ts? I had an issue similar to this which ended up being cause by some out of date compiled files.

Comment: @Code2Code no, cleaned everything up. Is there enough to have `export class Api { ... }` or do I need to instantiate it in that file too?

Comment: It is enough to export, since TS is a static type checker.

Answer (score 297, accepted):

Check that you don't have **`noEmit`** set to `true` In your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: yes, it works like that, but no js files are created. I was expecting that webpack will create a bundle.js file

Comment: "noEmit": false is necessary, but also make sure the files ou want to bundle (and their refs) are in "include" in tsconfig.json. Was not expecting the noEmit issue with Webpack.

Comment: Also check for `noEmitOnError` not being set to `true`!

Comment: This worked for me as well when coverting a simple react app to typescript. Thank you!

Comment: Also emitDeclarationOnly should not be true !!!

Answer (score 10):

First change webpack config entry like index.js to index.tsx.
Second make sure rule added for tsx file like:

```js
{
  test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    loader: "babel-loader",
    options: {
      presets: [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
      ],
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: why not use `ts-loader` with the `ts` file? @Soshiv Upreti

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624202/why-use-babel-loader-with-ts-loader @Dolphin